# How to control Odrive with Raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-3b+, serial, driver

How to interface Odrive with RPi? didn't find much information on the internet so want to know who has done something like this before.

trying to use this code:-

```
import odrive
import time
import serial

ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)  #change ACM number as found from ls /dev/tty/ACM*
ser.baudrate=9600

print("Searching for ODrive...")
odrv0 = odrive.find_any()
print("Odrive detected!")
```

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: What is odrive and how is this related to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I spent 10 minutes browsing its web pages. I agree that you should not find "much" info about it.

Comment: this is odrive motor controller - https://odriverobotics.com/shop/odrive-v36 & I want to interface it with RPi

Comment: Yes, but this motor drive board is $119.  Has anybody tried it before?  Can you give me the link?

Comment: I tried with Arduino and works with great precision

Comment: Ah, let me see. If you are using a library for Arduino C++, you need to use a similar library or module for Rpi python. Do you have such a module that we can download from GitHub?

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107983/edit) your question and add the additional information there instead in comments (link, Arduino).

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What information you want? The question isn't clear enough. Please add more information or show us the exact problem you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a python library called odrive which I used to control odrive from my pc. I decided to use Arduino instead so no problem for now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.